# C++ callback to class function

Tags: c++, class, arduino, lora

I'm using the Arduino IDE and the things network arduino library to create a LoRa mote.

I have created a class which should handle all the LoRa related functions. In this class I need to handle a callback if i receive a downlink message. 
The ttn library has the onMessage function which I want to setup in my init function and parse another function, which are a class member, called message. 
I'm getting the error "invalid use of non-static member function".

```
// File: LoRa.cpp
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "LoRa.h"
#include <TheThingsNetwork.h>

TheThingsNetwork ttn(loraSerial,debugSerial,freqPlan);

LoRa::LoRa(){ 
}

void LoRa::init(){
  // Set the callback
  ttn.onMessage(this->message);
}

// Other functions

void LoRa::message(const uint8_t *payload, size_t size, port_t port)
{
  // Stuff to do when reciving a downlink
}
```

and the header file

```
// File: LoRa.h
#ifndef LoRa_h
#define LoRa_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include <TheThingsNetwork.h>

// Define serial interface for communication with LoRa module
#define loraSerial Serial1
#define debugSerial Serial


// define the frequency plan - EU or US. (TTN_FP_EU868 or TTN_FP_US915)
#define freqPlan TTN_FP_EU868



class LoRa{
  // const vars



  public:
    LoRa();

    void init();

    // other functions

    void message(const uint8_t *payload, size_t size, port_t port);

  private:
    // Private functions
};


#endif
```

I have tried:

```
ttn.onMessage(this->message);
ttn.onMessage(LoRa::message);
ttn.onMessage(message);
```

However none of them worked as I had expected.

Comment: A non-static member function needs an *object* to be called upon. If you don't have an object, you can't use non-static member functions. Once you have an object, I suggest you look into [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved the problem by making the message function a normal function outside the class. Not sure if it is good practice - but it works.

```
// File: LoRa.cpp
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "LoRa.h"
#include <TheThingsNetwork.h>

TheThingsNetwork ttn(loraSerial,debugSerial,freqPlan);

void message(const uint8_t *payload, size_t size, port_t port)
{
  // Stuff to do when reciving a downlink
}

LoRa::LoRa(){ 
}

void LoRa::init(){
  // Set the callback
  ttn.onMessage(message);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to call a member function (that means, a function belonging to a member of a class type) without using a class member. That means, what you'd usually do is instantiate a member of your class LoRa first, then call it like:

```
LoRa loraMember;    
loraMember.message();
```

Since you're trying to call that function from inside the class itself, without a member of the class calling the init(), you have to make the function static like:

```
static void message(const uint8_t *payload, size_t size, port_t port);
```

Then you can use LoRa::message() from anywhere as long as it's public, but calling it just like that will give you another compiler error, since the interface of message asks for "const uint8_t *payload, size_t size, port_t port". So what you'd have to do is call message like:

```
LoRa::message(payloadPointer, sizeVar, portVar);`
```

When you call ttn.onMessage(*functionCall*) what happens is that the function call gets evaluated, then what is returned by that function gets put into the parentheses and ttn.onMessage is called with that. Since your LoRa::message function returns nothing (void) you'll get another error here.

I suggest a good book on C++ basics to get you started - [book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should pass arguments to `massage` as indicated by its prototype:

`void message(const uint8_t *payload, size_t size, port_t port);`

Since `massage` returns void, it should not be used as an argument to other functions.